# Google Tag Manager not referencing jQuery? "$ is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

Going to start off by saying I have very limited experience with JS and jQuery, so I'm flailing around a bit here.

I've got a GTM custom HTML tag that uses jQuery to grab the text from label/legend elements associated with a specific error message class, and push each one to the dataLayer for event handling:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="error-push">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
        var errMsgs = document.getElementsByClassName("error_message");
        for (i = 0; i < errMsgs.length; i++) {
            var assocLabel = $(errMsgs[i]).closest(".field_error").find(".field_label").text();
            if(assocLabel) { dataLayer.push({'field-error': assocLabel}); }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I can get the function to run no problem when tested directly in my browser console. But when I run it via GTM, I get an Uncaught TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    <anonymous> https://example.com/form/?gtm_debug=1661509869380 line 348 > injectedScript:1
    jQuery 2
        e
        t
register:1:218
```

At first I thought that GTM was just firing the script before jQuery was loaded, so I included an extra line at the top of the script in GTM to check for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="error-push">
  typeof window.jQuery !== 'undefined' ? console.log(window.jQuery.fn.jquery) : 'jQuery not found!'
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() { ...
```

...And the console is returning "3.6.0", indicating that jQuery *is* loaded when the function runs. So where is the TypeError coming from?

Comment: Why do you call jQuery by its full function name everywhere except in the snippet? Why not use the full function name there too? Maybe jQuery is loaded in a way such that it does not create its $ alias.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Probably because I was copying and pasting other people's code, lol. Where in the snippet should I use the full function name?

Comment: instead of "var assocLabel = $(errMsgs[i])" you could try using "var assocLabel = jQuery(errMsgs[i])"

Comment: You do not need jQuery to access the neighbouring element. element.closest has been adopted from jQuery natively into all major browers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I think I tried using closest() without jQuery first but then it wouldn't let me use find() because it was an element and not an object? Can I still get around that without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

My personal practice for Google Tag Manger is not using jQuery within it.

Because it will have so many error that not sure why it comes up.

In your case :

I suggest you use the trigger `Dom Ready`. From what I know it is quite the same when you want to fire something as `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {}`

Comment: I'm open to using just JavaScript if someone knows how to do the same thing with it. I tried not using jQuery at first but couldn't find a way to access the cousin element in a way I could understand.